# Persistent data among tests with django and pytest

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

The idea behind this question is simple to understand but complex to solve: I need to share data among tests.

I have a Django project and I use [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [pytest-descibe](https://github.com/ropez/pytest-describe) for defining and running tests.

While in pytest the database is rolled-back after every test, in the "describe-way" it's common to share "context" among tests within the same describe. 
This makes writing tests more readable and fast to run, and allows to run all the assertions even if a single test fails in between.

For this reason I'd like to turn off the default behaviour of database rollback on each test and instead do it after the whole describe is run.

This is a simplified version of my tests:

```py
pytestmark = [pytest.mark.django_db]

def describe_users():
    email = 'foo@example.com'

    def test_create_a_user_and_it_exists():
        User.objects.create(email=email)
        assert User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()  # Pass

    def test_the_user_keeps_to_exist():
        assert User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()  # Fail
```

I tried using the fixture [db_access_without_rollback_and_truncate](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html?highlight=rollback#use-a-read-only-database) suggested on the documentation but it didn't work, database is still reset after each test.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fixture you are using is valid for `read only` database, for your requirement this is more appropriate - https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html?highlight=rollback#use-the-same-database-for-all-xdist-processes OR https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html?highlight=rollback#using-an-existing-external-database-for-tests

Comment: Maybe i didn't get how to use it but it seems not to work. However, I need something module-based and not session-based.

Answer (score 1):

First a warning: be aware that you could potentially compromise the validity of subsequent test cases when one of them does something unexpected to the database. Rollback is there to ensure unit test integrity. Having said that, here's an example based on `db_access_without_rollback_and_truncate` (shortened to `db_no_rollback`):

```
# Note: do not use pytestmark globally, because it will apply
# rollback access to everything. Instead apply it on an individual basis.

# Use this fixture wherever non-rollback database access is required.
@pytest.fixture
def db_no_rollback(request, django_db_setup, django_db_blocker):
    django_db_blocker.unblock()
    request.addfinalizer(django_db_blocker.restore)

# This test still uses the normal rollback.
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_start_empty():
    assert MyModel.objects.count() == 0  # PASS

# Create an object here.
def test_1(db_no_rollback):
    item = MyModel.objects.create(title='ABC')
    assert item.id == 1  # PASS

# It still exists here. Then we change it.
def test_2(db_no_rollback):
    item = MyModel.objects.get(title='ABC')
    assert item.id == 1  # PASS
    item.title = 'DEF'
    item.save()

# The change still persists.
def test_3(db_no_rollback):
    assert MyModel.objects.get(id=1).title == 'DEF'  # PASS

# This will pass, but the change won't persist.
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_4():
    item = MyModel.objects.get(title='DEF')
    assert item.id == 1  # PASS
    item.title = 'GHI'
    item.save()

# This will fail.
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_5():
    assert MyModel.objects.get(id=1).title == 'GHI'  # FAIL
```